# File open dynamic using Stream Reader

Tags: c#, json.net, filereader, streamreader

I need some help. I'm creating a method that gets a string with file name and read file json on the path the project, deserialize on an object.

But on the file open, I want to concatenate the path with the file name, it doesn't work.

```
public static ObjectXpto ObjectXptoType(string filename)
{
        ObjectXpto objectXpto = new ObjectXpto();

        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"..\project\Data\$"{filename}".json")) 
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            objectXpto = (ObjectXpto)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(ObjectXpto));
        }

        return objectXpto;
}
```

Comment: _File.OpenText($@"..\project\Data\{filename}.json")_

Comment: TBH, I would use [Path.Combine(string, string) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_); don't concatenate strings for paths.

Comment: pretty much you're missing the concat shortcut $ as steve said.  You only need @ if you are going multiline.

Comment: @JohnLord `you're missing the concat shortcut $` **no**, it's not a concat shortcut...

Comment: .. and @JohnLord `@` is not just for multiline, it also means you don't have to escape the backslashes.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Perhaps it's not the technical name of the shortcut but it's what he's using it for.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings

Comment: @stuartd great info.  I didn't know it did that also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safe way is to use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) or [Path.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.join?view=netcore-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8) :

```
var fullPath=Path.Combine(@"..\project\Data",$"{fileName}.json");
```

This takes care of any trailing backslashes in the folder string

Comment: This is case, I don´t need to use the StreamReader?

Comment: @AdrianoFukuda yes, you still do. You would pass `fullPath` to the `File.OpenText`.

Comment: using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(fullPath)) ?

Comment: @AdrianoFukuda yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $ and @ signs before the string to type in variable names within the string.

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText($@"..\project\Data\{filename}.json"))
```

Comment: Please do mark the post as answered. thanks @AdrianoFukuda

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
    public static ObjectXpto ObjectXptoType(string filename)
    {
        ObjectXpto objectXpto = new ObjectXpto();

        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText($"..\\project\\Data\\{filename}.json")) 
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            objectXpto = (ObjectXpto)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(ObjectXpto));
        }
        return objectXpto;

    }
}
```